# Polly 7 retry won't compile

Tags: c#, polly

In Polly 6, I could use an expression like this to retry a function that may throw an exception:

```
Policy
.Handle<Exception>(ex => true)
.WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
.Execute(() => DoSomething());
```

In Polly 7, this does not seem to work, but the documentation still suggests doing this.

It seems like `Handle<Exception>` returns a `PolicyBuilder` which does not have a `Retry` or `WaitAndRetry` method on it. `HandleResult<T>` does have these methods, but it can't be used for handling thrown exceptions.

How is this supposed to work in 7?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, verifiable example? - perhaps as a DotNetFiddle. This [exact copy-paste of your code in a DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F5EDxb) works, with Polly (latest) 7.1.1.

Comment: What's the point to have a predicate like this: ex => true?

Comment: It is filtering which exceptions to handle. In this case all exceptions.

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. Let me try to rephrase it: Do you use this handle all exceptions predicate in your production code or is it just a sample? BTW: are you still looking for an answer for this?

Comment: I have changed jobs since. I think we were using a predicate like that in production tnough